# Prevent Multiple Primary When the Checkbox is Checked

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Form where I want to limit the Data from my Drop Downlist when the checkbox is checked

So when the Is Primary checkbox is Checked , There will be no 2 Email address that the Is Primary is Both True !! That is what i Want to Prevent

[image]

So that When i Save theres a Message window that will Appear and Let the user know that he/she checked the checkbox for the Same Drop Down Value

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Worker", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactForm" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="workerId" name="workerId" value="@workerId" />
    <p>
        <label for="ddlContactType">
            Contact Type</label>
        <span>
             @Html.DropDownList("ddlContactType", new SelectList(ViewBag.ContactTypeList, "ID", "Display_Value", workerContactType), "[Please Select]",
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"class","validate[required] inputLong"}
                })
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="txtContactValue">
            Contact Value</label>
        <span>
            <input type="text" id="txtContactValue" name="txtContactValue"  class="validate[required] inputLong" value="" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkWorkerIsPrimary" id="chkWorkerIsPrimary" value="true"
                        checked="checked" />
             <label>
                 Is Primary?</label>
        </span>
        </p> 
        <p>
            <span>
               <input type="submit" id="btnAdd" class="styledButton" value="Add" />
            </span>
        </p>
    }
</div>
```

I need the Validation written in Javascript or Jquery but i dont know how to start :(

Thanks

Comment: You can handle that on the click event of the checkbox. Code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is where you begin.

```
$('#chkWorkerIsPrimary :checkbox').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);  
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        // do something
    } 
    else {
     //do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: i just want to validate on will i limit the contact type value. . I just need 1 IsPrimary every dropdown List data, Example i Add one Email Address and the Is Primary Checkbox is Checked it will save then when i picked Email Address Again and checked the Is Primary Checkbox , There is a Notification that only one IsPrimary in Email Address